# How to use SCP and AWS to share data from remote Ceph (S3) and a remote standard filesystem?

Tags: aws-cli, scp, ceph

I need to transfer data between machine A *(linux filesystem)* and machine B *(Ceph/S3 object filesystem)* from machine C *(the only one I can control)*. On machine C, I installed **aws cli** for my transfers.

I've worked out how to transfer from A to B: `scp user@A:/path/to/file >(aws s3 cp - s3://s3uri/)`

But I'm stumped for the transfer from B to A. I've tried lots of things without success. The command `aws s3 cp s3://s3uri/filename.txt >(scp - user@A:/path/to/file)` gives me this error:

```
-: No such file or directory
download failed: s3://s3uri/filename.txt to ../../dev/fd/63 [Errno 32] Broken pipe
```

it would seem that notation with a hyphen is not permitted in this writing style

The command `scp <(aws s3 cp s3://s3uri/filename.txt -) user@A:/path/to/file)` gives me this error:

```
/dev/fd/63: not a regular file
download failed: s3://s3uri/filename.txt to - [Errno 32] Broken pipe
```

Has anyone done this before?

Thanks for your help
Thierry

Comment: There isn't a reasonable way to get `scp` to read from a pipe and write it to a remote system. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/49900890/13317.

Comment: Hi @Kenster
Thank you for your reply. 
I did read what your link referred to. My question was not about the ethics or merits of my request. As we can't do otherwise (no administrator access to either A or B), we absolutely must find a solution to do what I described in my message ... without having to download a file (which weighs several dozen GB) locally and then send it to the remote servers.

Answer (score 1):

You can workaround by decomposing scp into a succession of ssh and cat :

`aws --quiet s3 cp ... >(cat) | ssh [serveur] 'cat > file.txt'`

When I test, the intermediate cat seems necessary for me else ssh reads the file content as the connection password which fails.
--quiet is necessary for me to avoid aws to write "N/N bytes transferred [...]" at the end of the new file.

If you can use sshpass to automatically pass the password, then you can remove these cat and --quiet :

`aws s3 cp ... >(sshpass -f file_with_password ssh [serveur] 'cat > file.txt')`

Comment: Also yes the hyphen - doesn't work with scp because it is not a bash standard, just a convention followed by some commands but not by scp